Problemas con el teclado en uno nodo local con el microcontrolador PIC16F886
Tengo que hacer un nodo local y uno remoto con el PIC16F886 para un proyecto de escuela. Probando el modo local donde selecciona uno de los tres modos disponibles, entrara en modo local, remoto o interconoceccion. Lo anterior se hace oprimiendo ya sea el 1, 2 o 3 del teclado. Esa parte funciona bien, pero para salir de cualquiera de los tres modos es oprimiendo culaquier tecla, es ahi donde falla. Si por ejemplo estoy en el modo local, donde en una pantalla LCD se exhibe la distencia con un signo + o -, dependiendo si se aleja o acerca, cuando quiero salir de vuelta para escoger alguno de los tres modos oprimiendo cualquiere tecla, no funciona.
#include <16F886.h>
#device ADC=10  // Especificamos que el ADC es de 10 bits

#FUSES NOWDT                    // No Watch Dog Timer
#FUSES NOBROWNOUT               // No brownout reset
#FUSES NOLVP                    // No low voltage programming, B3(PIC16) or B5(PIC18) used for I/O

#use delay(crystal=4000000)
#use rs232(baud=9600, parity=N, xmit=PIN_C6, rcv=PIN_C7, bits=8)

// Definiciones para la pantalla LCD
#define LCD_RS_PIN      PIN_C0                                   
#define LCD_RW_PIN      PIN_C1 
#define LCD_ENABLE_PIN  PIN_C2 
#define LCD_DATA4       PIN_C3                                    
#define LCD_DATA5       PIN_C4                                    
#define LCD_DATA6       PIN_C5                           
#define LCD_DATA7       PIN_A1

#include <lcd.c>
#include <KB_4x4_2.c>  // Incluye la librería del teclado matricial

float getDistance(float voltage) {
    float distance;

    if ((voltage <= 2.25) & (voltage > 1.27)) 
        distance = -9.6899224806201 * voltage + 31.0503875968992;
    else if ((voltage <= 1.27) & (voltage > 0.91))
        distance = -26.5521112166479 * voltage + 53.2559364476297;
    else if ((voltage <= 0.91) & (voltage > 0.72))
        distance = -50.7701980509275 * voltage + 75.7761710154041;
    else if ((voltage <= 0.72) & (voltage > 0.6))
        distance = -83.4046193327635 * voltage + 99.4636441402912;
    else if ((voltage <= 0.6) & (voltage > 0.51))
        distance = -113.2075471698122 * voltage + 117.6698113207552;
    else if ((voltage <= 0.51) & (voltage > 0.46))
        distance = -200.0000000000016 * voltage + 162.5000000000007;
    else if ((voltage <= 0.46) & (voltage > 0.41))
        distance = -215.5999999999999 * voltage + 168.6879999999999;
    else
        distance = -1; // Valor de error para voltajes fuera de rango

    return distance;
}

void main() {
    char key;
    int16 adc_value;
    float voltage, distance, prev_distance = 0;
    char direction;

    set_tris_a(0x01); // Configura AN0 como entrada
    set_tris_b(0xF0); // Configura B0-B3 como salida (teclado)
    set_tris_c(0x80); // RC6 como salida, RC7 como entrada

    lcd_init();
    kbd_init();
    setup_adc(ADC_CLOCK_DIV_32);
    setup_adc_ports(sAN0 | VSS_VDD); // Asegura que el Vref sea interno (VSS y VDD)
    set_adc_channel(0);
    delay_us(10);

    lcd_putc("\fMed. Distancia\nLocal/Remoto");
    delay_ms(3000);
    lcd_putc("\fLoc(1) Rem(2)\nConectar(3)");

    while (TRUE) {
        
        key = kbd_getc();

        if (key == '1') {
            // Modo local
            lcd_putc("\fModo Local");
            delay_ms(1000);
            while (TRUE) {
                adc_value = read_adc();
                voltage = adc_value * (5.0 / 1023.0); // Verifica que la referencia de voltaje sea 5.0V
                distance = getDistance(voltage);

                if (distance > prev_distance) {
                    direction = '+';
                } else {
                    direction = '-';
                }
                prev_distance = distance;

                lcd_putc("\fDistancia local:");
                lcd_gotoxy(1, 2);
                printf(lcd_putc, "%.1f cm %c", distance, direction);
                delay_ms(500);
                key = kbd_getc(); // Revisar teclado
                if (key != '\0') break; // Regresa al menú inicial si se presiona una tecla
            }
        } else if (key == '2') {
            // Modo remoto
            lcd_putc("\fModo Remoto");
            delay_ms(1000);
            while (TRUE) {
                adc_value = read_adc();
                voltage = adc_value * (5.0 / 1023.0); // Verifica que la referencia de voltaje sea 5.0V
                distance = getDistance(voltage);

                if (distance > prev_distance) {
                    direction = '+';
                } else {
                    direction = '-';
                }
                prev_distance = distance;

                printf("D:%.1f:%c\n", distance, direction); // Enviar datos al nodo remoto
                delay_ms(500);

                key = kbd_getc(); // Revisar teclado
                if (key != '\0') break; // Regresa al menú inicial si se presiona una tecla
            }
        } else if (key == '3') {
            // Conexión
            printf("?\n"); // Envía el carácter de conexión
            while (TRUE) {
                if (kbhit()) {
                    if (getc() == 'o') {
                        lcd_putc("\fConexion\nEstablecida");
                        delay_ms(3000);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                key = kbd_getc(); // Revisar teclado
                if (key != '\0') break; // Regresa al menú inicial si se presiona una tecla
            }
        }
    }
}


Que entrono de desarollo estas utiliizando? Para mi que esas demoras en cada bloque de if son demasiadas. No se si la libreria de teclado que se utiliza tiene funcion de debounce, no deberias poner 1000 ms de demora para procesar el oprime del boton. 100ms es mas que suficiente para hacer debounce. Yo combiaria esos bucles segundarios infinitos como lo siguente: while (kbd_getc() == '\0')
